# android list of devices empty

Tags: android, device

am trying android with eclipse in linux.

I got struck and restarted adb.

```
./adb kill-server
[raja@raja platform-tools]$ ./adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 

[raja@raja platform-tools]$
```

Then I tried to launch the helloworld.

I get this error,

```
 [2011-10-22 22:58:56 - HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
 [2011-10-22 22:58:56 - HelloAndroid] (null)
 [2011-10-22 22:58:56 - HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
 [2011-10-22 22:58:56 - HelloAndroid] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
 [2011-10-22 22:58:56 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!
```

Please help me fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps too trivial question, but did you start the device in Eclipse AVD manager?

Comment: am using the device that come with adroid4.0. It is listed in avd manager. Should I start this everytime I start eclipse?

Comment: Yes, the emulator device should be started to be able to run your application. If not started, it will be launched automatically if you run the application through Eclipse (Right-click project root folder > Run As > Android Application). If you want to change device, you can check out Right-click project root folder > Run As > Android Application > Run Configuration > Target.

Comment: was doing "project root folder > Run As > Android Application" but didn't start the device automatically, that is why I posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already create a new android device? you can do that on the AVD manager, remember that you need the API version you want downloaded, i.e Gingerbread, and create a new device with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The trick was to right click the **project itself**-> Run Configuration, and **not** the green "Run" button from the menu bar.